# Looker: Aggregate by Count

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, looker

I have data that looks like this:

```
User Id | Login Count
00000000| 0
00000001| 1
00000002| 1
00000003| 2
```

I'd like to visualize this data by the number of logins on the X axis and the count of users with that many logins on the Y axis:

```
4|
3|
2|   *
1| *   *
  _________
   0 1 2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done my going to the vis menu, then Plot, and toggle "Switch X and Y"  for example:

[image: before enableing]

Then, once it's enabled, it will render this:

[image]

Note that this option is only available for scatterplot, line, and area graphs.